# Trying to execute lerna run --parallel on a set of packages

Tags: node.js, lerna

I am using lerna to manage my mono repo.

I'd like to run a command in parallel towards a set of packages.

I tried the following but can't get it working:

```
lerna run start --parallel packages1 packages2
lerna run start --parallel --scope packages1 packages2
lerna run start --scope "packages1 packages2" --parallel
```

It doesn't execute "run start" on my scope but on all the packages I have.

What is the right syntax to define the scope? Couldn't find anything in the documentation for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

```
lerna run start --parallel --scope packages1 --scope packages2
```

should work.

According to their docs,

```
lerna run start --parallel --scope packages*
```

should also work, assuming you don't have a packages3 and packages4 that you don't want to run.

Comment: If your packages have the same prefix you can say `--scope @myrepo/{pkg1,pkg2}`

Answer (score 0):

Did You specify the pathes of your packages in lerna.json ?
Example:

```json
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*",
    "package1",
    "package2"
  ],
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

[Here for more informations](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#lernajson)

Answer (score -1):

```
lerna run start --parallel '{*/packge,*/packge2,*/package3,*/package4,*/package5}'
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.